# Query to determine the average duration from user sign-up to 1st purchase

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables in my PostgreSQL database:

```
users: id, created_at (timestamp)
purchases: id, created_at
```

A user can have multiple purchases. What I'm like to learn is, by users created in a particular month, what is the average length of time before they make their first purchase. And this should only include users that make 1 or more purchases.

Goal is for the data to look like so:

```
weeks_ago | Date Start | Date End | Total Users in Cohort | Total Users w >=1 Purchase | avg days to complete 1st purchase
```

What approach can I try?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . .  assuming the first purchase is always after the creation date, then you basically want to do the following:

- Aggregate the purchases to get the first purchase date (or use `distinct on`).
- `JOIN` that result to the `users` table.
- Summarize by month.

This looks like:

```
select date_trunc('month', u.created_at) as yyyymm,
       avg( u.created_at - p.created_at )
from users u join
     (select p.id, min(p.created_at) as first_created_at
      from purchases p
      group by p.id
     ) p
     on u.id = p.id
group by date_trunc('month', u.created_at)
```